# ¿Porque al usar la extension de code spell checker en visual studio me marca todo como error?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, extensiones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me marca como error letras y cosas que ni siquiera tendrian porque ser un error

Comment: No veo errores, lo que veo es que al estar en inglés lo que te subraya son palabras en español. Seguramente debe tener un diccionario